# is there similar to Selenide (Java) or Capybara (Ruby) selenium wrapper for Python?

Tags: python, software-testing

I found so many selenium wrappers for python... It's very hard to choose...

But I know what I want - something like Selenide or Capybara. Are there any alternatives in Python world?

The following "features" are needed:

- jQuery-style selectors, e.g.: `showPasswordChkbox = $(".show-pasword")`
- should style asserts: `showPasswordChkbox.shouldBe(checked)`
- Ajax support: each "should" always waits for its Condition to happen (with aibility to set timeout directly if needed), e.g.: `showPasswordChkbox.waitUntil(checked, 5000)`
- straightforward and easy way to implement own conditions that can be used in shoulds
- Autostart browser
- clear error messages: what element was looking, of what selector, why fail? actual value?
- screenshots per each failed "should" with link to screenshot in produced error message
- [desired] screenshots per each should with ability to set context and then get all "screenshots per context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started porting selenide to python:
https://github.com/yashaka/selene

Answer (score 2):

Elementium has a lot of what you are looking for:

https://github.com/actmd/elementium

Comment: Big thanks. Finally found it by myself too. This is exactly what I was asking for:)

Answer (score 1):

[Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides a high-level API to automate browser interaction.